# How to stop React from overtaking console error messages?

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, react-dom

Anyone know how to make React stop hiding/overtaking console errors?

If you see here, the error is reported to come from this "react-dom.development.js" file. Which is totally useless. I wanted to know **where in my actual code** the error is really happening.

[image]

I've set webpack's environment setting to "development". But it does not seems to change anything.

```js
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('development'),
    },
  }),
],
```

Comment: You haven't provided any code. Error is telling you you are returning Object(s) from some component and when you try to render that component React throws this error.

Comment: it's hard to provide the specific code. first, that variable mentioned in the error is located in several places. and no H1 actually contains that variable. so i can't really help much. especially not with this generic React error message.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you can't find where the error is happening. You can find it by searching where you tried to get 'total_unpaid_policy' and it says error is occured in a h1 tag in the next error prompt.

I hope it helps..

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention if that `total_unpaid_policy` variable is located in several places. and none are wrapped in an h1. that's why i'm quite frustrated with the way React handles this error.

Comment: I see, can you share Index function/component?